# PHP-How to add an "Enter passcode" screen before user accesses website

Tags: php

So I have a chatting site in PHP, but the problem is that anyone can access any "chatroom". Is there a way to add an "Enter passcode" text box to the site before they are able to access the real thing? And if possible I would prefer not using those JavaScript pop-ups. And for the people who really want to help, I don't need any CSS.

My code:

index.php:

```
<?php
 
session_start();
 
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    
     
    //Simple exit message
    $logout_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='left-info'>User <b class='user-name-left'>". $_SESSION['name'] ."</b> has left the chat session.</span><br></div>";
    file_put_contents("log.html", $logout_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
     
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: ../../index.php"); //Redirect the user
}
 
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}
 
function loginForm(){
    echo
    '<div id="loginform">
    <p>Please enter your name to continue!</p>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <label for="name">Name &mdash;</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>
  </div>';
}
 
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
 
        <title> Chat</title>
        <meta name="description" content=" Chat Application" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/chat.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        loginForm();
    }
    else {
    ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="menu">
                <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
                <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
            </div>
 
            <div id="chatbox">
            <?php
            if(file_exists("log.html") && filesize("log.html") > 0){
                $contents = file_get_contents("log.html");          
                echo $contents;
            }
            ?>
            </div>
 
            <form name="message" action="">
                <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" />
                <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // jQuery Document
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
                    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
                    $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
                    $("#usermsg").val("");
                    return false;
                });
 
                function loadLog() {
                    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height before the request
 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "log.html",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div
 
                            //Auto-scroll           
                            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                            }   
                        }
                    });
                }
 
                setInterval (loadLog, 2500);
 
                $("#exit").click(function () {
                    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
                    if (exit == true) {
                    window.location = "index.php?logout=true";
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

post.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    $text = $_POST['text'];
     
    $text_message = "<div class='msgln'><span class='chat-time'>".date("g:i A")."</span> <b class='user-name'>".$_SESSION['name']."</b> ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>";
    file_put_contents("log.html", $text_message, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem you have? Entering a passcode would be just another form field like the name you are already entering.

Comment: I'm asking how to use a passcode to match with my database and once they enter the right passcode they get brought to the chatting screen

Comment: You already know how to use a HTML form and send data to the PHP script, so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: My problem is that I need to match the "passcode" with a database, which I'm not so good at

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Your question does not mention anything about a database, where you have problems with. Please [edit] your question to include a description of the actual problem you have and what you have tried so far.

Comment: There are many tutorials on implementing user validation using PHP and a database.